# data was not stored in laravel and not getting any errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I tried to store data but data not store to database, the field in database and form input already match but still can't store data, and there is no actual message error. please help.

this is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'kabupaten' => ['required'],
        'provinsi' => ['required'],
        'unit' => ['required'],
        'satuan_kerja' => ['required'],
        'nama_area' => ['required'],
        'kode_area' => ['required']
    ]);
    Area::create($validatedData);

    return redirect('/dashboard/areas')->with('success','Area baru telah ditambahkan!');
}
```

this is the form input:

```html
<form action="/dashboard/areas" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="provinsi" class="form-label">Provinsi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="provinsi" name="provinsi" value="Jawa Tengah">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="kabupaten" class="form-label">Kabupaten</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kabupaten" name="kabupaten" value="Brebes">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="unit" class="form-label">Unit</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unit" name="unit" value="Pemerintah Kabupaten Brebes">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="satuan_kerja" class="form-label">Satuan Kerja</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="satuan_kerja" name="satuan_kerja" value="Pemerintah Desa Dumeling">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="nama_area" class="form-label">Nama Area</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama_area" name="nama_area">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="kode_lokasi" class="form-label">Kode Lokasi</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kode_lokasi" name="kode_lokasi">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And this is my area model:

```php
class Area extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_area';
    protected $guarded = [
        'id_area'
    ];

    public function aset(){
        return $this->hasMany(Aset::class, 'id_area');
    }
}
```

Thank you if there anyone can help me with this problem, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Make sure you're [ratelimiting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting) that endpoint :) and checking for duplicates if required

Answer (score 2):

So most likely your validation is failing, what you need to do is to display the results of the failed validation error messages, and you can do so in your blade file:

```
@if ($errors->any())
   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <div>{{$error}}</div>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

You may read more on how to display the errors here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

You can as well display it per input field or change the class of the input method, etc.. check the `@error` directive from here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#the-at-error-directive